# reference to UIPickerViewData used inside xib.file

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am using a UIPickeView inside a xib.file and then using that xib file as one of the views to Horizontal UIScroolView with page control.

The data of UIPicker is JSON Response coming from UrlSession.shared.dataTask().

How could I dynamically set the value for my Pickerview .

[image]

Comment: Is the xib file added to a ViewController? if so create an IBOutlet for the xib view to the ViewController and create an IBOutlet for the PickerView to the xib view, then access like, `vc.xibView.pickerView`

Comment: For Swift it's simply:
self.picker?.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)